# why variables in unnamed namespace has external linkage?

Tags: c++, extern, linkage

I know that unnamed namespaces makes variables' linkage external but it is also true that they can't be accessed from other translation units.

I also know that everything has a purpose in C++. So my question is that, why variables in unnamed namespace has external linkage even though they can't be accessed from other translation units.

Am I missing sth here ?

Thank you

Comment: They have internal linkage.

Comment: @MikeSeymour yes they do, you're thinking about named namespaces.

Comment: From the Standard 3.5-4: An unnamed namespace or a namespace declared directly or indirectly within an unnamed namespace has
internal linkage. ...

Comment: @imreal: Maybe you're right. Either that changed in C++11, or I've lost my sanity.

Comment: @Mike it changed in C++11, because that's what sensible compilers were doing anyway

Comment: @MikeSeymour it changed in C++11. I got it wrong too. imreal is right on this point